# Is there any way to get all of the css just from a single page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am wondering there is a tool such as a Google Chrome extension out there that will get all of the css displayed on the current page, and nothing else. For instance, when you use the developer tools in chrome and get the css you have the option to get the classes you hover over and it's neighbouring classes, or the ability to see the full CSS file for the whole site. I am looking for a way to get ALL of the css used on the current page and displayed all together, instead of me having to manually check each div and pasting it into notepad.

I figure there must be something out there that does this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried these myself, but [Pendule](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pendule/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi?hl=en) and [Quick Source Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb?hl=en) look promising.

I would just post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. :(